# accessing post data passed through web browser control -winforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm developing a winforms application, in which I have a web browser control, where I have to open certain web page based on the menu item clicked. This is how I'm calling the web page in app

```
System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding =  new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(); 
string postData = "username=xyz";
string header = "";
webBrowser.Navigate(url, "", encoding.GetBytes(postData), header);
```

How I can access postData values in the webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the page at `url` is also an ASP.Net page, then you can access it by:

```
String Username = Request.Form("Username");
```